# Is there a way for Prisma to create a date in a timezone other than UTC

Tags: javascript, mysql, next.js, prisma

I am creating a webpage in nextjs that tracks an inventory.
I am using [prisma](https://www.prisma.io/) to connect to my 'mysql' database. I want to create a new row that registers when a change is done to the inventory. In this row I want to include the date and time in which the row is created. The problem is that the date is generated in UTC+00:00 when i want for it to be generated in UTC-06:00.

This is the prisma schema model

```
model inventory_movements {
  moveNumber    Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  name    String    @db.VarChar(128)
  date    DateTime? @default(now()) @db.DateTime(0)
  amount  Decimal   @db.Decimal(11, 2)
  comment String?   @db.VarChar(128)
}
```

I use moment to generate the date and then change the timezone.

```
import moment from 'moment';
import 'moment-timezone';

prisma.inventory.create({
  data: {
    name: "product_name",
    amount: 1,
    comment: "comment on the change",
    date: moment().tz('America/Monterrey').format()
  }
});
```

The generated date is `'2022-12-11T00:21:29-06:00'`, but the database has another value `'2022-12-11 06:21:28'`

I tried another aproach in which the database generates the date automatically with default value. I configured the column to have a default value of `NOW()` which correctly generates the date.

I then deleted the date data from the prisma command, as such:

```
import moment from 'moment';
import 'moment-timezone';

prisma.inventory_movements.create({
  data: {
    name: "product_name",
    amount: 1,
    comment: "comment on the change",
  }
});
```

But i get the error:

```
error - unhandledRejection: PrismaClientValidationError: 
Invalid `prisma.inventory_movements.create()` invocation:

{
  data: {
    name: 'product_name',
    amount: '1',
    comment: 'comment on the change',
+   date: DateTime
  }
}

Note: Lines with + are required
```

Comment: Given that you track things that happened in the past, you should store the UTC time + the timezone name separate from each other. For example, have a separate `timezone` field that has `America/Monterrey` as a value. Do not use offsets.